# How to push a single image with multiple tags to a container registry?

Tags: ibm-cloud, docker-buildkit, container-registry

I'm currently using the following command to build an image with a tag:

```bash
buildctl build \
    --frontend dockerfile.v0 --opt filename=${DOCKER_FILE} --local dockerfile=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    ${BUILD_ARGS} --local context=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    --import-cache type=registry,ref=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME} \
    --output type=image,name="${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}",push=true
```

I want to add a new tag to the same image. I've tried what is suggested on [Buildctl command to tag multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691068/buildctl-command-to-tag-multiple-images), but it fails.

```bash
buildctl build \
    --frontend dockerfile.v0 --opt filename=${DOCKER_FILE} --local dockerfile=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    ${BUILD_ARGS} --local context=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    --import-cache type=registry,ref=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME} \
    --output type=image,name="${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG},${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest",push=true
```

```
error: invalid value acme.com/namespace/image-name:latest
```

I also tried the following, but it only creates the image with the `latest` tag, not both

```bash
buildctl build \
    --frontend dockerfile.v0 --opt filename=${DOCKER_FILE} --local dockerfile=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    ${BUILD_ARGS} --local context=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    --import-cache type=registry,ref=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME} \
    --output type=image,name="${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG},name=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest",push=true
```

What I want:

- 1 image with 2 tags: value of `IMAGE_TAG` and `latest`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Did you try "escaping the images", as described in that answer?  It seems to mean backslash before each double quote for the name=\"path:tag1,path:tag2\" ?

Comment: I tried it with no success. However, I managed to do it. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a difference between `name="foo"` and `"name=foo"`. The correct one in this case is the latter.

I tracked the issue that enabled this funcitonality https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/797. The comments show how to do it (depending on your environment escaping might be necessary; although, not always).

Following the scenario from the question, the propper way to **build and push a single image with multiple tags** is as follows (notice how it's `"name=`)

```bash
buildctl build \
    --frontend dockerfile.v0 --opt filename=${DOCKER_FILE} --local dockerfile=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    ${BUILD_ARGS} --local context=${DOCKER_ROOT} \
    --import-cache type=registry,ref=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME} \
    --output type=image,\"name=${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG},${REGISTRY_URL}/${REGISTRY_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest\",push=true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is tricky indeed but your answer did the trick